# Notepad with line numbers

Tags: windows-7, text-editors

I'm looking for a text editor with as few features as notepad, but with the addition of line numbers.

Does anyone know of such an application.

**Edit**

I've used Notepad++ and Notepad2 in the past and I'm not keen. I'm looking for something that really is as lightweight as Notepad (but with line numbers ;) (thanks for the suggestions so far though)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a good replacement and includes line numbers.

**Edit:** Following your edit saying that you'd tried Notepad++ - you could try [Metapad](http://liquidninja.com/metapad/). It's a quick standalone Notepad replacement - it doesn't display the line numbers down the side (like Notepad++ does), but it does display the cursor position (row/column) in the status at the bottom of the window which would effectively tell you what line number you're on when you're editing/viewing.

Answer (score 8):

You can use notepad with "Show statusbar" option checked (you can find it in View menu). And you will have actual line number displayed on that statusbar.

If you have this option "grayed" then you have to uncheck "Word wrap" option in Format menu.

Comment: Yes, that's from far the simplest solution if you need to check the row number of some text.

Comment: Worked for me. +1

Answer (score 2):

[Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) has line numbers. It's not as lean as Notepad but it is very light weight if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

[SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vim(1) or its graphical version gVim(2) Might be a little too hardcore though. For something simpler I'll recommend Extreme Editor(3), it's lightweight and has line numbers, just not in the traditional sense (the line number is displayed along with column number in the bottom left corner).

1: www.vim.org/download.php
  2: portablegvim.sourceforge.net/
  3: ufridman.org/extremeeditor.html

Sorry for the formatting of the links, but as I'm a new user Superuse doesn't allow me to post more than one link.

Comment: Suggesting Vi to somebody looking for something as simple as notepad seems like suggesting the space shuttle to somebody looking for a new bike.

Comment: I beg to differ. For hardcore users Vim can be heavily customised with plugins and keymappings etc but for light users you can just fire it up and begin typing away. Personally I use it for serious programming work as well as simple note taking. Another plus point is that it's so ubiquitous that it can be found on all major OS.

Comment: Extreme Editor looks good. Going to give that a whirl!

Answer (score 0):

Programmer's Notepad [(free download here)](http://www.pnotepad.org/) displays line numbers if you want, syntax highlighting, etc. for a wide variety of languages. I've used it a lot over the last few years.

A bunch of screen shots can be [found here](http://www.pnotepad.org/screenshots/).